# Error adding to ArrayList - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

This is a snippet of my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Spiral3{
    public static ArrayList<Integer> R = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    public static ArrayList<Integer> K = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    R.add(1);
    K.add(1);
    public static String pekare = "H";
```

All I'm trying to do here is create two arrays with the first element `int 1`. So R = [1], K = [1]. I get the following error:

```
Spiral3.java:8: error: <identifier> expected
    R.add(1);
         ^
Spiral3.java:8: error: illegal start of type
    R.add(1);
          ^
Spiral3.java:9: error: <identifier> expected
    K.add(1);
         ^
Spiral3.java:9: error: illegal start of type
    K.add(1);
```

What's going on here? Thankful for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
R.add(1);
K.add(1);
```

These statements should be inside some method or constructor or initializer block.

For example :

```
static {
    R.add(1);
    K.add(1);
}
```

Comment: Could I possibly add them in the initialization to avoid having to add them inside a method?

Comment: @user3128156 You can use a static initializer block (see my edit).

Answer (score 2):

If you want the list to be initialized to those values, you can pass it as List:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> R = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1)); 
public static ArrayList<Integer> K = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this;

```
  // create an array list
  ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

  System.out.println("Initial size of al: " + al.size());

  // add elements to the array list
  al.add("C");
  al.add("A");
  al.add("E");
```